# Can Aula gaming mouse driver install in Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, mouse

My gaming mouse, Aula H512, currently working fine but only with the default function of all the keys. Since this is a programmable mouse, is there any way I can download the software to change the key functions? or even sensitivity?

I tried `piper` and `ratbagctl` but these two not support the Aula mouse